# Using -> instead of direct function call

Tags: php, oop, syntax

In some classes I see a call to a function is like:

```
$this->ClearError();
```

When the function is residing in that class itself. How is the above approach different from a direct function call like:

```
return ClearError();
```

Comment: retagged to oop since it's not php5 specific

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PHP (unlike C++, for example), you need to use `$this->ClearError()` in order to call a method on the class. `ClearError()` calls the global `function ClearError()`.

Comment: By the way, some of my PHP developer friends are horrified that you can call the method without the `this` keyword in other languages. Of course, my C# & Java friends are horrified that there are global functions.

Comment: i use this.method() in Java (actually this.property way more) because it lets me very easily not mix up class and local properties.

Answer (score 2):

`$this->ClearError();`

Refers to the Function inside the Class.

`return ClearError()`

Calls the function which you defined outside the class of defined seperatly.

```
Class Demo {
  function _construct() {
   $this -> ClearError(); // refers function inside the class
  }

 function ClearError() {
  return ClearError(); // refers outside the classs
 }
}

function ClearError() {
  contents
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See sathish's answer - the reason for having methods in objects instead of just using functions, is that it allows a set of data to be bundled together, which makes referencing the particular data item a lot clearer.

C.

Comment: I think "Encapsulation" was the term you were looking for ;)

Comment: No, thats what I was /describing/ to someone who doesn't know a lot about OO